# Having multiple JNI libraries with OpenCV support

Tags: android, c++, opencv, cmake, android-ndk

I have a project that uses OpenCV in JNI, and when it has only one *.cpp/*.h file, it compiles and works as expected, with no issues.
Then I add another *.cpp/*.h to use in another activity, and link it in the CMakeLists.txt. If this new cpp file does not have any OpenCV calls inside, everything still works fine. The first activity can call its OpenCV functions as expected, and the second activity can call the standard JNI functions defined in its corresponding cpp file.
However, if I try to use any OpenCV, even just a simple `Mat` in this second cpp file, the project does not even compile, giving the following error:

```
D:/programming/tree-project/treedetect/app/src/main/cpp/processing.cpp:21: error: undefined reference to 'cv::Mat::Mat(int, int, int)'
D:/programming/tree-project/treedetect/app/src/main/cpp/processing.cpp:24: error: undefined reference to 'cv::Mat::~Mat()'
```

Every question and answer I have found up to now deals with a single cpp file and making it work. I don't want to put all the codes of different activities into a single cpp and make it 3k lines long, but I cannot make multiple libraries work together. How can I use OpenCV in more than one JNI libraries? Since a single library works, my guess is that there is something wrong with linking and cmake config.

For code details, the `detection` library always compiles and works as intended. The `processing` library does not compile if it includes any OpenCV code. Some important files are found below:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)




# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

include_directories(${OpenCV_DIR}/jni/include)
add_library( lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${OpenCV_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java4.so)

# Declares and names the project.

project("detection")
project("processing")

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             detection

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             detection.cpp )

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        processing

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        processing.cpp )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.


                       detection

                       processing


        lib_opencv
                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'TFLite Object Detection Demo App'
include ':app', ':lib_interpreter', ':lib_task_api'
include ':opencv'
project(':opencv').projectDir = new File(openCVSDK+'/sdk')
```

**gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
# OpenCV
openCVSDK=D\:\\libraries\\OpenCV-android-sdk\\4.5.2
```

**build.gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'de.undercouch.download'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.0.1111"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
                abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
                arguments "-DOpenCV_DIR=" + openCVSDK + "/sdk/native"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
    }
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    flavorDimensions "tfliteInference"
    productFlavors {
       // The TFLite inference is built using the TFLite Java interpreter.
       interpreter {
           dimension "tfliteInference"
       }
       // Default: The TFLite inference is built using the TFLite Task library (high-level API).
       taskApi {
           getIsDefault().set(true)
           dimension "tfliteInference"
       }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
            version '3.10.2'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.aar'])
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    interpreterImplementation project(":lib_interpreter")
    taskApiImplementation project(":lib_task_api")
    // OpenCV
    implementation project(path: ':opencv')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    // view model
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.felHR85:UsbSerial:6.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
}
```

**processing.cpp (one that does not work)**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <numeric>



using cv::Mat;


extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_org_tensorflow_lite_examples_detection_ImageProcessingViewModel_valueFromJNI(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                                  jobject thiz) {
    // This does not work
    Mat dummy(400, 800, CV_8UC1);
    return dummy.rows;
    // this does work
    return 42;
}
```

**Build Variants**

[image: Variants]

**error**

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\tpalh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\ninja.exe with arguments {-C D:\programming\tree-project\treedetect\app\.cxx\Debug\54133v1z\armeabi-v7a detection processing}
ninja: Entering directory `D:\programming\tree-project\treedetect\app\.cxx\Debug\54133v1z\armeabi-v7a'
[1/2] Linking CXX shared library D:\programming\tree-project\treedetect\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\54133v1z\obj\armeabi-v7a\libprocessing.so
FAILED: D:/programming/tree-project/treedetect/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/54133v1z/obj/armeabi-v7a/libprocessing.so 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\tpalh\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi24 --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/tpalh/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/tpalh/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=armv7-a -mthumb -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -frtti -fexceptions -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc_real.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind.a -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -shared -Wl,-soname,libprocessing.so -o D:\programming\tree-project\treedetect\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\54133v1z\obj\armeabi-v7a\libprocessing.so CMakeFiles/processing.dir/processing.cpp.o  -latomic -lm && cd ."
D:/programming/tree-project/treedetect/app/src/main/cpp/processing.cpp:21: error: undefined reference to 'cv::Mat::Mat(int, int, int)'
D:/programming/tree-project/treedetect/app/src/main/cpp/processing.cpp:24: error: undefined reference to 'cv::Mat::~Mat()'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

And the funny part is that the OpenCV library is actually recognized in the IDE for this cpp file: [image: fun]

Comment: BTW, it's possible to use easily the C++ API of OpenCV all from Java without having to deal at all with the NDK: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/opencv

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late, but if anyone else gets stuck here, it looks like a `cmake` problem , op is only including one file ->

```
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             detection

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             detection.cpp <--- *ONLY ONE FILE INCLUDED*
 )

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        processing

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        processing.cpp <--- *ONLY ONE FILE INCLUDED*
 )
```

This can be solved by using `GLOB_RECURSE` or something to find all needed files.

eg

```
# Automatically all files in a directory to a target
file (GLOB_RECURSE CHOPPER_SRCS CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
    "src/*.cpp"
    "src/*.h"
)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
        chopper

        # Sets the library as a shared library.
        SHARED

        # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
        ${CHOPPER_SRCS}
)
```

[source](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Chopper/blob/master/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt)

[**here's a link for a project which uses OpenCV native for android AND HAS MULTIPLE C++ FILES**](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Chopper/).